# PDF File Merge Based on Filename

Tags: pdf, merge, automation, filenames

I have large batches of pdf files that must be merged.

Folder1 FileName Explaination: invoice12-**105767**-1510781492.pdf - 105767 is the component that will match with a pdf filename in Folder2.

"**invoice12-**" First section of the filename. This can sometimes be "**invoice11-**" or "**invoice6-**" so merging based on character length became challenging. The "**invoicexx-**" are based on where in the system the file came from.

"**105767**" Second part of the filename. This is the key component for matching and merging. this will be the filename in Folder2 it belongs with.

"**-1510781492.pdf**" Third part of the filename is a system generated unique ID, which can contain more or less characters.

Folder1:

- invoice12-105767-1510781492.pdf
- invoice12-105768-1510781484.pdf
- invoice12-105769-1510781469.pdf

Folder2:

- 105767.pdf
- 105768.pdf
- 105769.pdf

OutputFolder:

Example I don't want to merge all the files in both folders into 1 huge file. I need them merged based on the Folder2 filename. (105767.pdf + invoice12-105767-1510781492.pdf) in that order specifically, also.

The final output should be three pdf files merged in order as follows:

- 105767.pdf + invoice12-105767-1510781492.pdf to make 1 file named 105767.pdf
- 105768.pdf + invoice12-105768-1510781484.pdf to make 1 file named 105768.pdf
- 105769.pdf + invoice12-105769-1510781469.pdf to make 1 file named 105769.pdf

I would appreciate any assistance with a way to automate this process. I merge over 800 files per day. This small automation would shave hours off my day and my wrist from carpel tunnel.

I primarily use Mac OS 10.13.1. I have looked around in Mac's "Automater" program and cannot figure out how to get it to do what I need. (I did figure out a great way to split files into single pages)

I downloaded pdftk server (since that is Mac compatible) but cannot figure out if this type of match and merge is capable with this program.

I have Adobe Acrobat DC Professional and it does not seem to have this match and merge function.

I am even open to other paid programs. I just need a fairly future-proof way of getting this mundane task done through automation on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the APDFL library examples that are provided with sample code.  These libraries are supported on Mac, but are not free.

https://dev.datalogics.com/adobe-pdf-library/sample-program-descriptions/c1samples/#mergedocuments

Here is a snippet of the code you would need to use:

```
APDFLDoc doc1 ( csInputFileName1.c_str(), true);
APDFLDoc doc2 ( csInputFileName2.c_str(), true);

// Insert doc2's pages into doc1. 
//    Here, we've stated PDLastPage, which adds the pages just before the last page of the target.
//    If we specify PDBeforeFirstPage instead, doc2's pages will be inserted at the head of doc1.
PDDocInsertPages ( doc1.getPDDoc(), 
                   PDLastPage, 
                   doc2.getPDDoc(), 
                   0, 
                   PDAllPages, 
                   PDInsertAll, 
                   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

doc1.saveDoc ( csOutputFileName.c_str(), PDSaveFull | PDSaveLinearized);
```